# Get Source Code From Search Results

Tags: search, phantomjs, google-search

I am working on a project to analyze HTML code from specific websites. I can use phantomjs to get the source of a single website, but what I'd like to do is be able to get the source for many websites using a search term.

Say I search "Music CD's" on Google. I'd like the application to click on a result, save the source then click on the next result and save the source. Also I'd like it to be able to navigate to the next page and do the same on all subsequent pages.

Any advice on tools that may help with this, or guidance on how I can program it myself would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can still use PhantomJS for that. If you don't want to write that much, you can use CasperJS which is based on PhantomJS with a nicer API.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using casperJS and it worked!